# create product category UL within XML package?

Tags: xml, xslt, html-lists, aspdotnetstorefront

I have created an xml package for ASPDOTNETSTOREFRONT which runs a query. The file then creates an UL where it creates product links. However i need another UL to show up for the category and the product links to show into within that.

```
<ul>Category 1</ul>
 <ul>
  <li>product 1</li>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

Something like the above?

Here is my xml package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<package version="2.1" displayname="Simple Product" debug="true" includeentityhelper="false">

    <!-- ###################################################################################################### -->
    <!-- Copyright AspDotNetStorefront.com, 1995-2011.  All Rights Reserved.                                    -->
    <!-- http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com                                                                     -->
    <!-- For details on this license please visit  the product homepage at the URL above.                       -->
    <!-- THE ABOVE NOTICE MUST REMAIN INTACT.                                                                   -->
    <!--                                                                                                        -->
    <!-- ###################################################################################################### -->

    <query name="Products" rowElementName="Product">
        <sql>
            <![CDATA[
                WITH Categories (ParentCategoryID, CategoryID, Name, ComputedLevel, Sort) AS
                    (
                    SELECT c.ParentCategoryID, c.CategoryID, c.Name, 0 AS ComputedLevel, CAST('\'+c.Name AS NVARCHAR(255))
                    FROM Category AS c
                    WHERE ParentCategoryID = 0
                    AND Deleted=0
                    AND Published=1
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT c.ParentCategoryID, c.CategoryID, c.Name, ComputedLevel + 1, CAST(s.Sort + '\'+c.Name AS NVARCHAR(255))
                    FROM Category AS c
                    INNER JOIN Categories AS s ON c.ParentCategoryID = s.CategoryID
                    WHERE Deleted=0
                    AND Published=1
                    )

                    SELECT ParentCategoryID, c.CategoryID, Sort, p.ProductID, p.Name, p.SEName
                    FROM Categories c (NOLOCK)
                    LEFT JOIN ProductCategory pc (NOLOCK) ON pc.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
                    JOIN Product p (NOLOCK) ON p.ProductID = pc.ProductID

                    ORDER BY 3,5
            ]]>
        </sql>

    </query>

    <PackageTransform>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:aspdnsf="urn:aspdnsf" exclude-result-prefixes="aspdnsf">
            <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

            <xsl:param name="LocaleSetting" select="/root/Runtime/LocaleSetting" />
            <xsl:param name="WebConfigLocaleSetting" select="/root/Runtime/WebConfigLocaleSetting" />
            <xsl:param name="XmlPackageName" select="/root/System/XmlPackageName" />
            <xsl:param name="SecID">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(/root/QueryString/sectionid) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/root/QueryString/sectionid" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:param>

            <xsl:param name="CategoryID">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="/root/System/PageName = 'showmanufacturer.aspx' or /root/System/PageName = 'showsection.aspx' or /root/System/PageName = 'showdistributor.aspx' or /root/System/PageName = 'showvector.aspx' or /root/System/PageName = 'showgenre.aspx'">0</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="/root/System/PageName = 'showcategory.aspx' and boolean(/root/QueryString/categoryid)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/root/QueryString/categoryid"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="(/root/System/PageName = 'showcategory.aspx' or /root/System/PageName = 'showproduct.aspx') and boolean(/root/Cookies/LastViewedEntityInstanceID) and /root/Cookies/LastViewedEntityName = 'Category'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/root/Cookies/LastViewedEntityInstanceID"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:param>

            <xsl:param name="AncestorID">
                <xsl:for-each select="/root/EntityHelpers/Category//Entity[EntityID = $CategoryID]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*/EntityID"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:param>

            <xsl:param name="ParentID">
                <xsl:for-each select="/root/EntityHelpers/Category//Entity[EntityID = $CategoryID]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="parent::*/EntityID"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:param>

            <xsl:param name="CatID">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(/root/QueryString/categoryid) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/root/QueryString/categoryid" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:param>


            <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:element name="ul">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <![CDATA[accordion3]]>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Products/Product">
                        <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="''"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:template>



            <xsl:template match="Product">
                <xsl:param name="prefix"></xsl:param>
                <xsl:param name="eName" select="aspdnsf:GetMLValue(Name)" />
                <li >
                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="$prefix" />-->
                    <xsl:if test="number(ParentEntityID) != 0">
                        <!--<span class="catMark">&gt;&gt;</span>&#160;-->




                        <a href="{concat('p-',ProductID,'-',SEName,'.aspx')}">
                            <xsl:if test="EntityID = $CategoryID or descendant::Entity/EntityID = $CategoryID">
                                <xsl:attribute name="style">font-weight:bold</xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$eName"/>
                        </a>



                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="number(ParentEntityID) = 0">
                        <div class="menuText">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$eName"/>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="count(child::Entity)&gt;0">
                        <ul >
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="Product">
                                <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="concat($prefix, '&#160;&#0160;')"/>
                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                        </ul>
                    </xsl:if>
                </li>
            </xsl:template>


        </xsl:stylesheet>
    </PackageTransform>
</package>
```

The UL is created here:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:element name="ul">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <![CDATA[accordion3]]>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Products/Product">
                        <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="''"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:template>
```

And here is where the product link is created:

```
    <xsl:template match="Product">
        <xsl:param name="prefix"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="eName" select="aspdnsf:GetMLValue(Name)" />
        <li >
            <!--<xsl:value-of select="$prefix" />-->
            <xsl:if test="number(ParentEntityID) != 0">
                <!--<span class="catMark">&gt;&gt;</span>&#160;-->

                <a href="{concat('p-',ProductID,'-',SEName,'.aspx')}">
                    <xsl:if test="EntityID = $CategoryID or descendant::Entity/EntityID = $CategoryID">
                        <xsl:attribute name="style">font-weight:bold</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$eName"/>
                </a>


            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="number(ParentEntityID) = 0">
                <div class="menuText">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$eName"/>
                </div>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="count(child::Entity)&gt;0">
                <ul >
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Product">
                        <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="concat($prefix, '&#160;&#0160;')"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </ul>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
```

EDIT: ADDED XML extract:

```
<Product>
  <ParentCategoryID>77</ParentCategoryID>
  <CategoryID>78</CategoryID>
  <Sort>\Box Product\Accessories\AA990F</Sort>
  <ProductID>299</ProductID>
  <Name>Air compressor</Name>
  <SEName>air-compressor</SEName>
</Product>
```

Comment: Could you, please, also provide a complete ( but as small as possible) XML document that is the input for the XSLT transformation?

Comment: added an edit at the end of the page. it shows an extract of the XML..

Comment: also it seems to just add each product link to each li, which is wrong as i wont be able to create a flyout menu like this. I need each category to have its own UL/Li... know wat i mean?

Comment: OK, but the provided XML doesnt have anything like: `/root/EntityHelpers/Category` . Even if someone wants to help, there's no way to guess the exact XML that is to be transformed.

Comment: PD24, I dont know what you mean, a question is meaningful if there is an XML document and a transformation and the result -- and when anyone can apply this transformation on the given XML and repro the result. At present the XML is missing -- if the provided transformation is applied on the provided XML the result most probably will be empty. So long with any effort to understand the question ... :(

Comment: :( i see... its private data so its hard for me to provide this... i will post back if i can provide all 3

Comment: PD24, you can give us a very simplified version (completely different data and only similar structure) and when you get a solution, you can adapt it to your specific data.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer because may someone face this problem in future..
Use this code to render products with categoies.

**Example:**

- Category 1

  ```
  .Product 1

  .product 2
  ```
- Category 2

  ```
  .Product 1
  .Product 2




  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
  <package version="2.1" displayname="Simple Product" debug="false" 
  includeentityhelper="false">   
   <query name="Products" rowElementName="Product">
  <sql>
    <![CDATA[
              WITH Categories (ParentCategoryID, CategoryID, Name, 
           ComputedLevel, Sort) AS
                  (
                  SELECT c.ParentCategoryID, c.CategoryID, c.Name, 0 AS 
                     ComputedLevel, CAST('\'+c.Name AS NVARCHAR(255))
                  FROM Category AS c
                  WHERE ParentCategoryID =@CatID
                  AND Deleted=0
                  AND Published=1
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT c.ParentCategoryID, c.CategoryID, c.Name, 
                ComputedLevel + 1, CAST(s.Sort + '\'+c.Name AS 
                 NVARCHAR(255))
                  FROM Category AS c
                  INNER JOIN Categories AS s ON c.ParentCategoryID = 
                s.CategoryID
                  WHERE Deleted=0
                  AND Published=1
                  )

                  SELECT ParentCategoryID, c.CategoryID,C.Name as 
                  CategoryName, Sort, p.ProductID, p.Name, p.SEName
                  FROM Categories c (NOLOCK)
                  LEFT JOIN ProductCategory pc (NOLOCK) ON pc.CategoryID = 
                  c.CategoryID
                  JOIN Product p (NOLOCK) ON p.ProductID = pc.ProductID

                  ORDER BY 3,5
                    ]]>
                      </sql>
                   <queryparam paramname="@CatID"          
                    paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="CatID"                                     

  sqlDataType="int"     defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@SecID"          paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="SecID"                                         sqlDataType="int"     defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@ManID"          paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="ManID"                                         sqlDataType="int"     defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@DistID"         paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="DistID"                                        sqlDataType="int"     defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@GenreID"        paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="GenreID"                                       sqlDataType="int"     defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@VectorID"       paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="VectorID"                                      sqlDataType="int"     defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@locale"         paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="LocaleSetting"                                 sqlDataType="varchar" defvalue="en-US"  validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@CustLevelID"    paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="CustomerLevelID"                               sqlDataType="int"     defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@AffID"          paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="AffiliateID"                                   sqlDataType="int"     defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@ProdTypeID"     paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="ProductTypeFilterID"                           sqlDataType="int"     defvalue="1"      validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@pgnum"          paramtype="request"   requestparamname="pagenum"                                       sqlDataType="int"     defvalue="1"      validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@InvFilter"      paramtype="appconfig" requestparamname="HideProductsWithLessThanThisInventoryLevel"    sqlDataType="int"     defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@entityname"     paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="EntityName"                                    sqlDataType="varchar" defvalue=""       validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@StoreID"        paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="StoreID"                                                           sqlDataType="int"       defvalue="1"      validationpattern="" />
      <queryparam paramname="@FilterProduct"  paramtype="runtime"   requestparamname="FilterProduct"                                                   sqlDataType="bit"     defvalue="0"      validationpattern="" />
    </query>

    <PackageTransform>
      <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:aspdnsf="urn:aspdnsf" exclude-result-prefixes="aspdnsf">
        <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

        <xsl:param name="LocaleSetting" select="/root/Runtime/LocaleSetting" />
        <xsl:param name="WebConfigLocaleSetting" select="/root/Runtime/WebConfigLocaleSetting" />
        <xsl:param name="XmlPackageName" select="/root/System/XmlPackageName" />
        <xsl:param name="SecID">

          <xsl:variable name="ShowSubcatsInGrid" select="aspdnsf:AppConfig('ShowSubcatsInGrid')" />
          <xsl:variable name="EntityName" select="/root/Runtime/EntityName" />
          <xsl:variable name="EntityID" select="/root/Runtime/EntityID" />


          <xsl:variable name="CurrentEntity" select="/root/EntityHelpers/*[name()=$EntityName]/descendant::Entity[EntityID=$EntityID]" />

          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(/root/QueryString/sectionid) &gt; 0">
              <xsl:value-of select="/root/QueryString/sectionid" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:param>

        <xsl:param name="CategoryID">         
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/root/System/PageName = 'showmanufacturer.aspx' or /root/System/PageName = 'showsection.aspx' or /root/System/PageName = 'showdistributor.aspx' or /root/System/PageName = 'showvector.aspx' or /root/System/PageName = 'showgenre.aspx'">0</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="/root/System/PageName = 'showcategory.aspx' and boolean(/root/QueryString/categoryid)">
              <xsl:value-of select="/root/QueryString/categoryid"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(/root/System/PageName = 'showcategory.aspx' or /root/System/PageName = 'showproduct.aspx') and boolean(/root/Cookies/LastViewedEntityInstanceID) and /root/Cookies/LastViewedEntityName = 'Category'">
              <xsl:value-of select="/root/Cookies/LastViewedEntityInstanceID"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:param>

        <xsl:param name="AncestorID">

          <xsl:for-each select="/root/EntityHelpers/Category//Entity[EntityID = $CategoryID]">
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*/EntityID"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:param>

        <xsl:param name="ParentID">         
          <xsl:for-each select="/root/EntityHelpers/Category//Entity[EntityID = $CategoryID]">
            <xsl:value-of select="parent::*/EntityID"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:param>

        <xsl:param name="CatID">

          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(/root/QueryString/categoryid) &gt; 0">
              <xsl:value-of select="/root/QueryString/categoryid" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:param>

        <xsl:template match="/">
          <xsl:element name="ul">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
              <![CDATA[accordion3]]>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Products/Product">
              <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="''"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="Product">
          <xsl:param name="prefix"></xsl:param>
          <xsl:param name="eName" select="aspdnsf:GetMLValue(Name)" />
           <xsl:variable name="oldname" select="'old'" /> 
          <li >
            <!--<xsl:value-of select="$prefix" />-->

            <xsl:if test="number(ParentEntityID) != 0">
              <!--<span class="catMark">&gt;&gt;</span>&#160;-->

              <!--<xsl:if test="$oldname != CategoryName">-->
            <xsl:if test ="not(preceding-sibling::Product[(CategoryName/text() = current()/CategoryName/text())])">
              <h1>
                <xsl:value-of select="CategoryName"/>
              </h1>             
                   <!--<xsl:variable name="oldname" select="CategoryName" />-->
                  <!--<xsl:copy>
                   <xsl:value-of name="oldname" select="CategoryName"/>
                  </xsl:copy>-->

                </xsl:if>

              <a href="{concat('p-',ProductID,'-',SEName,'.aspx')}">
                <xsl:if test="EntityID = $CategoryID or descendant::Entity/EntityID = $CategoryID">               
                <xsl:attribute name="style">font-weight:bold</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="$eName"/>
              </a>



            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="number(ParentEntityID) = 0">
              <div class="menuText">
                <xsl:value-of select="$eName"/>            
              </div>
            </xsl:if>      

            <xsl:if test="count(child::Product)&gt;0">

              <ul >
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Product">
                  <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="concat($prefix, '&#160;&#0160;')"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
              </ul>
            </xsl:if>
          </li>
        </xsl:template>


      </xsl:stylesheet>
    </PackageTransform>
  </package>
  ```